# Bootstrap modal make full screen for mobile version

Tags: html, css

```css
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .modal-full-mobile {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content modal-full-mobile">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Let's say there is a standard modal.

Let's say on a mobile phone, when we rotate the screen, this window should stretch, and be the full width and height of the mobile phone, as in the screenshot

[image]

I added a class with styles to try and do it, is this the right approach?

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .modal-full-mobile {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont use bootstrap so they probably is a better way but  height:100dvh; on the .modal-full-mobile and .modal-dialog margin:0 important; in your media query should work.

Comment: Here is my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-joliot-semx07?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a full width modal on mobile screen size with this piece of css code :

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    margin : 0;
  }
  .modal-full-mobile {
    width : 100vw;
    height :100vh;
  }
}
```

The `.modal-dialog` classname has margin so we need to make sure it has 0 margin on mobile size screens .